# Is html and body styling at the same time an issue?

Tags: html, css

just a fast simple coding practice question:

- is assign the same CSS to **html** and **body** at the same time always an issue? Or should it be alright?

Sometimes we see them grouped, others we see people separating them for some unidentified reason, it makes me wonder, even though I never had any problems with grouped or ungrouped styling.

Comment: I'd avoid it. Assigning a background image twice, for example, may decrease performance.

Comment: Are you asking if there is a reason for writing a CSS page and then including CSS inline with the HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please refer to this **[article](http://phrogz.net/css/htmlvsbody.html)** as it describes the differences between the `body` and the `html` elements

Comment: A mere link is not an appropriate answer. You should summarize which answer it gives to the question asked.

Comment: As you can see the OPs question is very wide and it is not specific. Have you even looked at the article that i linked? It explains exactly what the OP has asked...

Answer (score 0):

Setting the same CSS declarations on `html` and `body` is an issue. For example, setting `margin: 10px` on both them would create a double margin. Setting `font-size: 60%` on both would cause double reduction of font size

Since `html` consists of `head` and `body` only and `head` is normally not displayed at all, it is normally adequate to set properties on `body` if you want to apply the page as a whole.

There are special cases where you may need to set properties on `html`, too. For example, for historical reasons, if you set background on `body` without setting background on `html`, the `body` background covers the entire page – which may or may not be what you want. Setting background on `html` affects this: then `body` background will be applied to the area occupied by `body` only.